# Can I save a tmap file using names referenced within a list?

Tags: r, r-markdown, tmap

I'm trying to automatically name a jpg output using a character list. This is an Rmarkdown file I use for reporting. For each month I summarise groundwater statistics and produce a basic Rmardown html.  I automatically save the maps to a folder I specify in the script. The maps always have the name GLmap.jpg.  I would like to use an appropriate name such as the year and month. Is there a way to do this?? Here's what I've tried so far

```
Library(tmap)
data("World")

test_map <- tmap::tm_shape(World)+
  tmap::tm_polygons("HPI")
```

Now I specify the year and month that I want

```
Curdate <- Sys.time() %m+% months(-1) 
Curedatemnyr <- as.character(format(Curdate, '%Y %B'))
```

Now I try to save it with a name that references by year and month

```
tmap::tmap_save(test_map,"'Curedatemnyr'_GLmap.jpg")
```

This doesn't reference the year and month from the list just gives the exact name i.e. 'Curedatemnyr'_GLmap.jpg instead of 2020 March_GLmap.jpg.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `paste0` :

```
tmap::tmap_save(test_map,paste0(Curedatemnyr, '_GLmap.jpg'))
```

Comment: So simple :) ...thank you. I also shared this with a few other beginners and they LOVED the tip too - so thanks form them too

Comment: This worked perfectly but what if I want to save these images to a new folder?? ```tmap::tmap_save(test_map,paste0(Curdatemnyr, 'tmap_folder/_GLmap.jpg'))```

Comment: okay I found out how to do this - this should work  ```tmap::tmap_save(GLmap,paste0('tmap_folder/', Curdatemnyr,'_GLmap.jpg', sep =""))```

Answer (score 0):

I am getting errors on the line

`Sys.time() %m+% months(-1)`

I am just trying to walk through your example and was getting errors, I don't know why. but I think Ronak Shah above gave you a the right answer

Comment: I just re-tested by copying the script above and it worked for me.  The solution by Ronak worked perfectly.